# In MVC3 how do I get validation messages to use my custom ModelMetadataProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a custom ModelMetadataProvider, which sets the displayname based on adding spaces after capital letters in the property name:

```
public class ModelMetadataProviderPlus : ModelMetadataProvider
{
    private readonly ModelMetadataProvider _BaseProvider;

    public ModelMetadataProviderPlus(ModelMetadataProvider baseProvider)
    {
        _BaseProvider = baseProvider;
    }

    private void SetMissingDisplayName(ModelMetadata modelMetaData)
    {
        if (modelMetaData.DisplayName == null && modelMetaData.PropertyName != null)
        {
            modelMetaData.DisplayName = modelMetaData.PropertyName.AddSpacesAfterCaps();
        }
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> GetMetadataForProperties(object container, Type containerType)
    {
        var Result = _BaseProvider.GetMetadataForProperties(container, containerType);

        return Result.Select(r =>
        {
            SetMissingDisplayName(r);
            return r;
        });
    }

    public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForProperty(Func<object> modelAccessor, Type containerType, string propertyName)
    {
        var Result = _BaseProvider.GetMetadataForProperty(modelAccessor, containerType, propertyName);

        SetMissingDisplayName(Result);

        return Result;
    }

    public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForType(Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType)
    {
        var Result = _BaseProvider.GetMetadataForType(modelAccessor, modelType);

        SetMissingDisplayName(Result);

        return Result;
    }
}
```

I configure the MVC framework to use it using

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new ModelMetadataProviderPlus(ModelMetadataProviders.Current);
```

This all works fine, however the validation error messages don't seem to use this provider, as the error message for the `[Required]` attribute says (for example): `The DefectCount field is required.`.

I use nInject, so i tried doing:

```
kernel.Bind<ModelMetadataProvider>().ToConstant(new ModelMetadataProviderPlus(ModelMetadataProviders.Current));
```

but although the labels etc. appeared correctly the validation messages still didn't.

I've searched for a while now and although I've found a couple of places where the same issue is noted, I can't find anything with a solution.